# Convergence in distribution of a function of bernoulli rv's

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to find the limit in distribution of a sequence.  The problem is stated like this:

For i ∈ N, let X<sub>i</sub> be i.i.d. with Bernoulli(1/2) distribution. Let Y<sub>0</sub> = 0 and let Y<sub>i+1</sub> = X<sub>i</sub>(Y<sub>i</sub> + 1).

(a) What is the limit in distribution of the sequence (Y<sub>i</sub>: i ∈ N)? 
(b) Does the sequence converge in any other senses? 
(c) Does the sequence converge uniformly in distribution? I.e. is there some function ε(n) such that
|P<sub>Y∞</sub>(E) − P<sub>Y<sub>n</sub></sub>(E)| ≤ ε(n) for all events E?

For part (a), I know I need to first find the CDF of Y<sub>i</sub> in terms of x<sub>i</sub> but I don't know how to obtain this since the sequence is defined recursively.  I listed the terms for the first four terms in the sequence Y<sub>i</sub> as follows

Y<sub>0</sub> = 0 
Y<sub>1</sub> = x<sub>0</sub> 
Y<sub>2</sub> = x<sub>0</sub>x<sub>1</sub> + x<sub>1</sub> 
Y<sub>3</sub> = x<sub>0</sub>x<sub>1</sub>x<sub>2</sub> + x<sub>0</sub>x<sub>2</sub> + x<sub>2</sub> 
Y<sub>4</sub> = x<sub>0</sub>x<sub>1</sub>x<sub>2</sub>x<sub>3</sub> + x<sub>1</sub>x<sub>2</sub>x<sub>3</sub> + x<sub>2</sub>x<sub>3</sub> + x<sub>3</sub>

But how do you obtain Y<sub>i</sub> in terms of X<sub>i</sub>?

Once I know this, I will use the known CDF of X to compute the CDF of Y, and then computing the limit as n goes to infinity to find the limit in distribution of Y.  Does this procedure make sense?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply draw a probability tree, you will be able to see a pattern emerging for eg. the $y1$ is a rv taking values 0 and 1 with 1/2 probability each so $y2$ is a rv taking values $(0+1).0 ,(0+1).1,(1+1).0,(1+1).1$, same way if you continue the pattern is formed.
$P(y_{n})=k$ is given by $\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}, k\neq n, and \frac{1}{2^{n}}, k=n $.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion with the probability tree.  Also, does this mean that the sequence does not converge in any of the other senses (a.s., m.s., p.) and also that it converges uniformly in distribution since each Y has the same distribution?